# C - Recursive function for minimum gap in array

Tags: c, recursion, optimization

I'm trying to **optimize** a function that, given an array of N **int**, return the minimum difference between an element and the **previous** one. Obviously the function is just for array with a dimension >=2.
For example, given the array {2,5,1}, function returns -4 . 
I tried to write my code, but I think it is really **intricate**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 4
/*Function for the difference, works because in the main I already gives one difference*/
int minimodiff(int *a, int n, int diff) {
  if (n==1) {
    return diff;
  }
  if (diff>(*(a+1) - *a))
     return minimodiff(a+1, n-1, *(a+1)-*a);
  else return minimodiff(a+1, n-1, diff);
}

int main() {
  int a[N]= {1,8,4,3};
  printf("%d", minimodiff(a+1, N-1, *(a+1)-*a));
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to avoid to pass the first difference in **main**, but doing everything in the recursive function. 
I can use as header file stdio.h / stdlib.h / string.h / math.h . Thanks a lot for the help, I hope that this can give me a better **understanding** of the recursive functions.

Comment: You forgot to return the results of `minimoddiff` from the recursive function. You should have gotten a warning about it. If not, turn on compiler warnings, probably with `-Wall`.

Comment: I wrote it in the text of the question! It works even without the return, that's not the probem; I'm asking how to optimize it to avoid passing the first "difference" from the main!

Comment: Well, you have to have correct code before there is any point optimising it. "it works even without the return". Really? then what is the point of having that code if it is called and not returned? Might as well delete it right?

Comment: You are surely more good than me in developing, I'm just at the start of a Computer Science Degree and out teacher said us that there isn't difference between returning the value and doing that, for the scope of the functions. I'm editing the text using return, thanks for the info.

Comment: @L.Repetti You're using [***undefined behavior***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), the C standard's way of saying when it happens the compiler can do whatever it wants. Your compiler decided to guess at your intent and make it work. Others might not. In C "it works" means "it happens to work on my machine with this compiler and this phase of the moon, but it might not work on a different machine, or compiler, or phase of the moon." Unlike some other languages, C does not return the last evaluated expression. You ***cannot*** leave off the `return` and expect it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`minimodiff(a+1, N-1, *(a+1)-*a)` is a weak approach to use recursion for it uses a recursion depths of `N` which can easily overwhelm system resources depth limit.  In such a case, a simple loop would suffice.

A good recursive approach would halve the problem at each call, finding the minimum of the left half and the right half.  It may not run faster, but the maximum depth of recursion would be `log2(N)`.

```
// n is the number of array elements 
int minimodiff2(const int *a, size_t n) {
  if (n == 2) {
    return a[1] - a[0]; 
  } else if (n <= 1) {
    return INT_MAX;
  }
  int left = minimodiff2(a, n/2 + 1);  // +1 to include a[n/2] in both halves
  int right = minimodiff2(a + n/2, n - n/2);
  return (left < right) ? left : right;
}

int main() {
  int a[]= {1,8,4,3};
  printf("%d", minimodiff2(a, sizeof a/ sizeof a[0]));
}
```

Comment: The `if( n <= 1 )` inside the `if( n <= 2 )` condition reads awkward. Was it to save a comparison in the common case? Maybe a `switch` and changing `n` to `size_t` to avoid negatives would achieve that and be more readable? `switch(n) { case 2: return a[1] - a[0]; case 1: case 0: return INT_MAX; }`.

Comment: @Schwern Yes, `if( n <= 2 )` inside for comparison save.  `n` used as type `int` to match OP's approach, although `size_t` is better. Re-wrote, but this part of code is not the key issue.  Bisection and `log2(n)` stack depth is the key point.  A re-work could further cope with `int` overflow and return a pointer to the smallest diff or `NULL` on short arrays.

Comment: That's the approach I really like best, thanks a lot! also, i didn't know that array lenght can be found using that sizeof trick!

Comment: @L.Repetti It only works for stack allocated arrays because the compiler knows how big it is. You can't do it for a heap allocated array (ie. `malloc`) or even a stack pointer that's been passed into a function. Assuming 4 byte integers and 8 byte pointers, in `main` `sizeof(a)` will be 16 (4 * 4 byte integer). But in `minimoddiff2` it will be 8 (1 * 8 byte pointer).

Answer (score 2):

When doing a min calculation, recursive or otherwise, it makes the initial condition simpler if you set the min to the highest possible value. If you were using floating point numbers it would be `Infinity`. Since you're using integers, it's [`INT_MAX` from limits.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#limits.h) which is defined as the highest possible integer. It is guaranteed to be greater than or equal to all other integers.

If you were doing this iteratively, with loops, you'd initially set `diff = INT_MAX`. Since this is recursion, `INT_MAX` is what gets returned when recursion is done.

```
#include <limits.h>

static inline int min( const int a, const int b ) {
    return a < b ? a : b;
}

int minimodiff( const int *a, const size_t size ) {
    if( size <= 1 ) {
        return INT_MAX;
    }

    int diff = a[1] - a[0];
    return min( minimodiff(a+1, size-1), diff );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The recursive approach is a bad idea because extra memory and function calls are used.
Anyway, your question is about avoiding the first difference.
You can use a centinel.
Since the parameter diff is an int variable, it is not possible to obtain a value greater than INT_MAX.
Thus, your first call to minimodiff can be done by giving the value INT_MAX as the argument corresponding to diff.
Besides, the standard header limits.h must be #include'd at top, to make visible the INT_MAX macro.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you for the memory. I am at the start of a CS degree and our teacher is giving us these exercise to make us understanding the process of recursion. So, I hope for a way to avoid INT_MAX or something like that and I struggled to search another way (using static / passing parameters) but nothing.

Comment: @L.Repetti Don worry, if you stick with CS, you'll find using recursive approaches become second nature.